# Java project not compiling in Eclipse following import from filesystem

Tags: java, eclipse

I have some Java projects (not Maven) on my old Windows system.  The source files, the class files and all the JAR files are on the C:\ drive.  I have copied the entire source tree (.java files), object tree (.class files) and all the JAR files to an external drive, **making sure that all the files are exactly at the same locations, relative to the root**.

On a different system I installed the same version of Eclipse (2019-03) and I imported the projects on that instance of Eclipse, from the external drive.  I manually edited the `.classpath` files for the projects, to factor in the change in the drive paths for all the files (from C: to the correct letter drive on the new system).

In my opinion I fully replicated the old environment in the new Eclipse instance.  **However, I am missing something** because the source files are not getting compiled in the new Eclipse instance: neither upon editing existing files nor upon adding new files.

Attempting to run the Java applications in the new Eclipse instance is giving the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class pkg_name.class_name Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pkg_name.class_name

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you didn't just port the source code/libraries and do a fresh project/build?

Comment: @Rogue  That is what I thought I was doing.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to copy the actual project information/etc into a new environment (e.g. eclipse's project files, resulting built files, etc). Instead, you should basically "import" the project in eclipse as a new project, targetting just your src+libs. (Granted, it's been 15 years since I've touched eclipse in a serious manner).

Comment: i would do it differently. Pick a proper build system like Gradle or Maven and make a project.. I use Maven so would use a Maven archetype to create a Java project then copy my source into the right place. That way, you're not tied to an IDE. You can import the Maven project into Eclipse or another IDE